# PHP > syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

was getting some errors before as was running PHP 5.3 so fixed that with upgrading to PHP 5.4 but not getting this error... any ideas?

ERROR:

> [Thu Aug 11 00:02:27 2016] [error] [client 90.200.49.107] PHP Parse
>   error:  syntax error, unexpected '$object' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /src/Shopify/Client.php on line 370

LINE 370: yield $object; (from function below)

PHP

```
public function getResourcePager($resource, $limit = NULL, array $opts = []) {
    $current_page = 1;
    if (!isset($opts['query']['limit'])) {
      $opts['query']['limit'] = ($limit ?: $this->default_limit);
    }
    while (TRUE) {
      $opts['query']['page'] = $current_page;
      $result = $this->get($resource, $opts);
      if (empty($result)) {
        break;
      }
      foreach (get_object_vars($result) as $resource_name => $results) {
        if (empty($results)) {
          return;
        }
        foreach ($results as $object) {
          yield $object;
        }
        if (count($results) < $opts['query']['limit']) {
          // Passing "page" # to Shopify doesn't always implement pagination.
          return;
        }
        $current_page++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you are asking why you are not getting this error with php 5.4?

Comment: Generators are added in PHP 5.5. You can't use `yield` in 5.4.

Comment: No i am getting that error now since upgrading to PHP 5.4

Comment: Ahh ok, i dont want to risk upgrading to PHP 5.5 right now as its a production server and running lots of sites so dont want to risk any impact. Is there a code fixture to work around for now?

Comment: So it was getting a different error in 5.3? Either way it can't work.

Comment: Yea those other errors were from short code arrays hence why upgraded to 5.4... is there no code chnages i can make to fix the error in question without having to push onto 5.5?

Comment: Return an array and loop in the caller, like you always had to do before generators were added.

Comment: @James take alook at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728384/syntax-error-t-variable-using-php-generators

Comment: sorry im new to php myself, ill try and give it a go though :)

Answer (score 0):

[Generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) in php are available from php >= 5.5.

Comment: Thought as much, the previous issues i was having i resolved by updating to 5.4 but playing with fire as lot of sites running on this server and dont want to keep upgrading PHP incase it effects some sites... is there a alternative code chnage i can make to resolve it?